# Calling findviewbyid for Main GridLayout returns null

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to call `findviewbyid` for `GridLayout` but where ever I place it returns null. I called it `onCreate()` method after setting `contentView` and inflating ViewStub. All children from `content_pytanie1.xml` returns properly except `mQuestionLayout`.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pytanie1);
    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
    stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_pytanie1);
    stub.inflate();
     mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
     mImageName = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iV_pytanie);
     mButtonChoice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
     mButtonChoice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        ....
    mQuestionLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout3); //returns null
}
```

This `GridLayout` is in `content_pytanie1.xml` layout. No matter how I changed it for `RelativeLayout`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pl.epsotesty.epsotestynumeryczne.pytanie1Activity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout3"
    >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iV_pytanie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tV_p"
                android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Question"
                android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                 />
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/choice1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="fkdl;avnvbnsdk"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/choice2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="dsakdlvnvbnvnkd"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/choice3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cdsadvnbvbndas"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/choice4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ddsadbvnva"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/choice5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Envnvnvnnvnvbnnnmbmbnmb"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp" />
            </RadioGroup>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wyjasnienie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="Wyjaśnienie:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tekstwyjasnienia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="tekst wyjaśnienia"
        android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zaznaczenie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="zaznaczono"
        android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="lista"
        android:textAppearance="@style/QuestionsAnswers" />
</GridLayout>
```

This is `activity_pytanie1.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pl.epsotesty.epsotestynumeryczne.pytanie1Activity"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tVtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="title"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tVcT"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="600"
                 />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonkoniec"
                    android:layout_width="26dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/exit"
                    android:onClick="onClickEndTest"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:progress="100"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBar2"
        android:layout_above="@id/toolbar"
        >
        <ViewStub
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
            android:id="@+id/layout_stub" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: `content_pytanie1.xml` or `activity_pytaniel` ???

Comment: GridLayout is in content.pytanie1.xml

Comment: Put a xml of `activity_pytaniel1` and `content_pytaniel1` add those edit your question

Comment: Try `mQuestionLayout = (GridLayout) stub.findViewById(R.id.gridLayout3);`

Comment: Its null. As a field too.

Comment: There is no connection between your two layouts

Comment: What u mean? I call all Views onCreate method from content_pytanie1.xml with succes except this Main GridLayout.

Comment: Make sure you tag me so I can get a notificaton @Xenolion. You get all notifications because you wrote the question!

Comment: @Xenolion I've edited the code for my activity with calling all children views of GridLayout properly except GridLayout.

Comment: I have already answered you question see below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the ViewStub layout in xml:

```
<ViewStub
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
    android:layout="@layout/content_pytanie1"
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub" />
```

and then:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
stub.inflate();
```

Or programatically:

```
ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_pytanie1);
viewStub.inflate();
```

> Explanation:

The line

`android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"`

means that the id of the inflated layout will be `message_layout` but your `GridLayout` has id `gridLayout3` which is why it is `null`.

So either remove the line:

`android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"`

and then do:

```
mQuestionLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout3);
```

or just do:

```
mQuestionLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.message_layout);
```

Comment: @Januszj. So did it work after adding `android:layout="@layout/content_pytanie1"`

Comment: No sir, I got this from the begining, stub isn't null.

Comment: This is it i removed android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout" and it works now. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

To access a `View` from `ViewStub` here is what you do:

```
View view = stub.inflate(); //view is an inflated View
mQuestionLayout = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gridLayout3);
```

This line:

```
stub.inflate();
```

`return`s a `View` which you will use to access a `GridLayout`.

Comment: Its still null.

Comment: Did you put the word `view` to be `view.findViewById()`.

Comment: Yes sir, its null.